# Set Parent Div Height to Child Div Height?

Tags: css

I have to set the height of the parent Div to something as I want some transition/ animation when the div disappears so the height is slowly set to 0.

My problem is the transition doesn't work if I don't set a height but if I do the parent doesn't take the height of the child.

Comment: Can you please create a minimum reproducible example?.

Comment: I believe anyone with a moderate understanding of Cascading Style Sheets would understand my explanation without the need for a "minimum reproducible example".

Comment: @Mark Please check my answer.

Comment: You can´t apply a transition to height. Use max-height or transform instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not animate the `height` of an element without set it to an absolute value. But you could try to use the `transform` property.

If you do not want to use the `transform` property and really want to animate the `height` you need to use a JS function, which computes the height of the parent element at the beginn of the transition.

**Edit:** Added code snipped with JS animation.
You have to edit my code when there is some `padding` or `margins` on the parent element.

```js
  function startTransition() {
      // Get element which is animated
      let element = document.getElementById('animated');
      // Get element's height
      let height = element.getBoundingClientRect().height;
      // Apply element's height as absolute value
      element.style.height = height + 'px';
      // Make sure that height is set using setTimeout
      setTimeout(() => {
         // Add class wich handels animation
         element.classList.add('parent__animate');
      }, 10);
}

// Start animation after 1s
 setTimeout(() => {
     startTransition();
 },1000);
```

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
    transition: height 2s linear;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.parent__animate {
    height: 0px !important;
}

.child {
    position: relative;
    background: green;
}

.child span {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="animated" class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <span>Content</span>
        <span>with</span>
        <span>dynamic</span>
        <span>height</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="background: red;">
    <span>Next element</span>
</div>
```

```css
.parent{
   position: relative;
   transform: scaleY(1.0);
   transform-origin: top center;
   transition: transform 2s linear;
}

.parent:hover{
  transform: scaleY(0);
}

.child{
   position: relative;
   background: red;
}

.child span{
   display: block;
}
```

```html
Hover over parent element to start the transition.

<div class="parent">
   <div class="child">
      <span>Content</span>
      <span>with</span>
      <span>dynamic</span>
      <span>height</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is exactly what I'm looking thank you, just wondering is there a way to start the animation on click instead of after 1s?

Comment: I start the animation after 1s just for demonstration purpose. Of course you can start the animation when you want, for instance in HTML ````<button onclick="startTransition()">Click me!</button>```` or triggered via a JS ````eventListener````, e.g. ````let button = document.getElementById('myButton'); button.addEventListener('click', () => {startTransition();});```` Also check out other ````EventListener```` such as ````transsitionstart```` and ````transitionend```` which can be very helpful when dealing with JS animations. Please mark my answer as accepted answer when it fits your needs.